# JavaScript take sum of diagonals of nested array with varying lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array where each array is one less in length than the array prior. I want to take the sum of elements diagonally and can't figure out how.

Here is a table representation of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Table]

In JavaScript the nested array is as follows:

```
let outArr = [];
const intArr= [0,2,4,6,8,10];
for (let i = intArr.length; i >0; i--) {
  outArr.push(intArr.slice(0,i));
}
```

I want my result array to be `[0,2,6,12,20,30]`. Do I use a triple nested loop? One for the output array and then two loops for the inner/outer array?

Comment: will you need to support dynamically sized arrays? or are these the only arrays in the solution? are you using a 2D array? can you list all of your data? seems like you would be using 6 different arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array once, keeping track of the current cumulative sum and adding it to the array on each iteration. (Note that the diagonal sums here are just the prefix sums of the array.)

```js
let outArr = [];
const intArr= [0,2,4,6,8,10];
let curr = 0;
for (const x of intArr) outArr.push(curr += x);
console.log(outArr);
```

For the more general case of diagonal sums, you can use a nested loop like so:

```js
let arr = [[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 0, 2],[1, 2],[0]];
let res = [];
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i; j++) sum += arr[j][arr[j].length - 1 - i];
  res.push(sum);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Would this also work is the nested arrays wern't the same values, but still the same pattern of length? For example `[[0,1,2,3],[0,0,2],[1,2],[0]]`? Apologies, I should clarify this in my question. Thanks for this elegant solution though.

Comment: @Yolo_chicken I've updated my answer for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to get the indexes that give you the diagonal values. Keep two counters and increase one and decrease one and do it within bounds for each iteration.

As per your code if `intArr` is the nested array with all rows, then this would return you the diagonal sums.

```js
let finalArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <intArr.length; i++) {
  let temp = 0, k=i;
  for(let j=0;j<=i;j++){
    temp += outArr[j][k--];
  } 
  finalArr.push(temp);
}
```

**There is also a way easier way to do this** if you don't want to work with the nested array since this is essentially the cumulative sum, so you don't need the nested array.

```js
let intArr= [0,2,4,6,8,10];
let cumulative = 0, finalArr = [];;
for (let x of intArr) {
   finalArr.push(cumulative += x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map every element to the sum of itself to all elements with index smaller that itself.

- Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to perform the mapping
- Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to perform the addition

```js
const 
    intArr = [0,2,4,6,8,10],
    
    outArr = intArr.map(
        (v,i,a) => a.slice(0,i+1).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
    );
    
console.log( outArr );
```

**Alternatively .....**

You could tweak your code a little to produce this version that's more efficient than the one above:

```js
const 
    outArr = [],
    intArr = [0,2,4,6,8,10];
    
for( const [i, v] of intArr.entries() ) {
    outArr.push( (outArr[i-1] || 0) + v );
}

console.log( outArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ];
const array2 = [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ];
const array3 = [ 0, 2, 4, 6 ];
const array4 = [ 0, 2, 4 ];
const array5 = [ 0, 2 ];
const array6 = [ 0 ];

const sum0 = array1[0];
const sum1 = array1[1] + array2[0];
const sum2 = array1[2] + array2[1] + array3[0];
const sum3 = array1[3] + array2[2] + array3[1] + array4[0];
const sum4 = array1[4] + array2[3] + array3[2] + array4[1] + array5[0];
const sum5 = array1[5] + array2[4] + array3[3] + array4[2] + array5[1] + array6[0];

const result = [
  sum0,
  sum1,
  sum2,
  sum3,
  sum4,
  sum5 ];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get last elements of the array, on first index insert first one in result array and from next index add lastly inserted value from result and current value.

```js
function getDiagonalSum(arr) {
  const lastArrays = [];
  const result = [];
  arr.forEach(currentArray => {
    lastArrays.push(currentArray[currentArray.length - 1]);
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < lastArrays.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      result.push(lastArrays[i])
    } else {
      let total = lastArrays[i] + result[i - 1];
      result.push(total);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2],
  [1]
];
const result = getDiagonalSum(arr);
console.log(result);
console.log("Your array input...")
const userArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [4, 4, 4, 4],
  [6, 6, 6],
  [8, 8],
  [10]
];
const userResult = getDiagonalSum(userArray);
console.log(userResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let inputArr=[]; let sumEntry =[]
       
       
        inputArray.reverse().forEach((subArr)=>{
       sumEntry.push((subArr.reduce((l,r)=>l+r,0));
        });
inputArray.reverse().push(sumEntry);
```